# How do I get (reasonably recent versions of) Angular.dart and Polymer.dart to live together?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-polymer

I, like many others, am trying to get Angular.dart to work w/ Polymer.dart. I'm also using Polymer's core-elements, which is the main reason I'd like to stick w/ Polymer. I've got Polymer + core-elements working fine, but when I introduce Angular in the mix, I can't get past the mess of dependency constraints.

```
 dependencies:
      angular: any
      #angular_node_bind: any // I'd like to introduce this later
      shadow_dom: any
      browser: any
      polymer: ">=0.11.0 <0.12.0"
      core_elements: ">=0.0.6 <0.1.0"
      firebase: ">=0.1.0 <0.2.0"
    transformers:
      - polymer:
          entry_points:
              - web/index.html
    dependency_overrides:
      browser: any
```

When I introduce the `angular: any` line I get:

```
Incompatible version constraints on html5lib:
- angular 0.0.8 depends on version >=0.8.7 <0.9.0
- polymer 0.11.0+1 depends on version >=0.11.0 <0.12.0
```

And here's my `pubspec.lock`:

```
# Generated by pub
# See http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/glossary.html#lockfile
packages:
  analyzer:
    description: analyzer
    source: hosted
    version: "0.15.7"
  args:
    description: args
    source: hosted
    version: "0.11.0+1"
  barback:
    description: barback
    source: hosted
    version: "0.14.0+3"
  browser:
    description: browser
    source: hosted
    version: "0.10.0+2"
  code_transformers:
    description: code_transformers
    source: hosted
    version: "0.1.4+2"
  collection:
    description: collection
    source: hosted
    version: "0.9.4"
  core_elements:
    description: core_elements
    source: hosted
    version: "0.0.6"
  csslib:
    description: csslib
    source: hosted
    version: "0.10.0+1"
  firebase:
    description: firebase
    source: hosted
    version: "0.1.0"
  html5lib:
    description: html5lib
    source: hosted
    version: "0.11.0+1"
  logging:
    description: logging
    source: hosted
    version: "0.9.1+1"
  observe:
    description: observe
    source: hosted
    version: "0.10.1+2"
  path:
    description: path
    source: hosted
    version: "1.2.1"
  polymer:
    description: polymer
    source: hosted
    version: "0.11.0+5"
  polymer_expressions:
    description: polymer_expressions
    source: hosted
    version: "0.11.2"
  quiver:
    description: quiver
    source: hosted
    version: "0.18.2"
  shadow_dom:
    description: shadow_dom
    source: hosted
    version: "0.10.0"
  smoke:
    description: smoke
    source: hosted
    version: "0.1.0+1"
  source_maps:
    description: source_maps
    source: hosted
    version: "0.9.2+3"
  stack_trace:
    description: stack_trace
    source: hosted
    version: "0.9.3+2"
  string_scanner:
    description: string_scanner
    source: hosted
    version: "0.0.3"
  template_binding:
    description: template_binding
    source: hosted
    version: "0.11.0"
  utf:
    description: utf
    source: hosted
    version: "0.9.0"
  web_components:
    description: web_components
    source: hosted
    version: "0.4.0"
  yaml:
    description: yaml
    source: hosted
    version: "1.1.1"
```

My repo: https://github.com/DaveNotik/dart-stack

Suggestions?

Related:

- https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1212
- https://plus.google.com/+NestorLedon/posts/R8P5AgHpQRc
- https://plus.google.com/112211372649695610825/posts/bWQ3dBLkvKT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a matter of the right dependency overrides ultimately.

Something like this:

```
name: my-app
version: 0.0.2
dependencies:
  angular: 0.12.0
  angular_node_bind: any
  browser: any
  polymer: ">=0.11.0 <0.12.0"
  core_elements: ">=0.0.6 <0.1.0"
  paper_elements: any
  meta: ">=0.8.8 <0.9.0"
transformers:
- angular:
    html_files:
    - web/index.html
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/index.html
    - web/index2.html
    - web/index3.html
dependency_overrides:
  polymer: ">= 0.11.1-dev < 0.12.0"
  browser: any
  web_components: 0.4.0
  analyzer: ">=0.15.6 <0.16.0"
  html5lib: ">=0.11.0 <0.12.0"
```